# Adding Colour To Text In C With Bloodshed

Tags: c

Is this possible?

I know it's possible in the command prompt using COLOR ##

but is it possible in C using bloodshed?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible, yes. Portable, no. Bloodshed has nothing to do with it. It's a matter of outputting the appropriate escape sequences for the console you're using.

Comment: Bloodshed kind of does have to do with it -- the IDE uses mingw, and presumably also the cygwin terminal; if so ANSI sequences will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on *nix, osx, or using cygwin msys on windows, your terminal should support the ANSI sequences Fred Larson mentions (not sure about osx).  The normal windows terminal does not.  But **bloodshed** can use cygwin, so you're in luck.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOLDMAGENTA "\033[1;35m"
#define BOLDGREEN "\033[1;32m"

int main(void) {
    printf("%shello %sworld\n", BOLDMAGENTA, BOLDGREEN);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this leaves the terminal in bright green, but if your prompt sets colours, that will get reset.

Here's some explanation of ANSI escape codes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 2):

What operating system? What terminal do you have available? Note that this has nothing to do with C, let alone bloodshed. You output a string which the terminal may or may not choose to interpret as a color. You have to see how to do that with your terminal. The solution of course is not portable. One such example for a terminal supporting escape sequences is

```
printf("\\x1b[1;33mThis is yellow\\x1b[m(Back to default)\n");
```

You may be interested in [ANSI terminal's color escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

You may also want to look for libraries that do that for limited number of terminals. For example, [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) could help you in Linux.

Comment: Those don't have anything to do with bash, it's the (ANSI compliant) terminal bash is running inside.  Since that's usually the case, .bashrc files often use them with the PS env variables.

Comment: @goldilocks, you are right, the terminal is the one understanding the color. I'll fix the text